# For HTML5 local storage, do I need openDatabase?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I've been playing around with HTML5 local storage, using localStorage.getItem("something") and localStorage.setItem("something","somevalue") and it's working just fine. Of course it's all conditional upon the localStorage window object existing.

I'm only storing one string, so I'm wondering whether I need this openDatabase call that I've read about. Half the examples I've found don't mention it at all, the other half seem to imply that it's a basic part of using local storage.

While I'm here, is local storage cross-domain or is it tied to the domain of the site from which it was stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing I've ever looked at concerning localStorage mentioned `openDatabase`. That's probably for webSQL storage, which isn't really used much, and only works in Safari/Chrome.

LocalStorage is same-domain, just like ajax calls.

Comment: Great. I hoped I wouldn't need it, and thanks on the same-domain info. Also great :) Here's the mis-information I most recently read: http://geekswithblogs.net/NatasaG/archive/2011/06/13/html5-localstorage.aspx

Comment: @Dee Definitely misinformation. There's some good information out there on openDatabase, [including a brief overview here](http://creativepark.net/blog/entry/id/1191), but the bottom line is that it's very SQL-driven, and AFAICT only good for a few niche uses (cookies + server-side storage + localStorage cover almost everything in a more programmer-friendly way). When the HTML5 spec was first announced there was a bunch of weirdness insisting on openDatabase, and I guess some of that has held over.